# HTML hyperlinks not working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

```
     <div class="item slides">
      <div class="slide-12"></div>       
      <div class="hero3">  
          <h1>Reach out at</h1>      
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/sowmiya-nagarajan/" 
          class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
          <a href="https://github.com/strangest-quark" class="fa fa-
          github"></a>
          <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/strangely-quark" 
          class="fa fa-snapchat-ghost"></a>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/nagarajan.sowmiya" 
          class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/strange._.quark/" 
          class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
      </div>    
    </div>
```

The hyperlinks in the above code snippet are not clickable. It could be a problem of another overlapping div. The links work when I use tab.

I tried z-index in different combinations, but none of them seem to work!

Find the complete html and css file in the following links:

1. [CSS](https://github.com/strangest-quark/Portfolio/blob/master/index.css)
2. [HTML](https://github.com/strangest-quark/Portfolio/blob/master/index.html)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: There's no content in those links. What is there to click on?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] where the links are at least visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links have no content inside them. What you can do if you want icon only links is to put the `fa-*` classes on a `span` or `i` tag inside the `a` tag like so:

```
<a href="https://example.com" >
    <span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span>
</a>
```

This then causes the `a` tag to actually have content and be clickable.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I works also with a single space character as content, leaving the Font-Awesome class in the anchor tag. However, the question says nothing about using font awesome.

Answer (score 3):

I added some text inside the anchor tags. But it seems you are needing to show them just as Font Awesome icons. In that case a single space character will be enough. Or well a `&nbsp;`

```
  <div class="hero3">  
      <h1>Reach out at</h1>      
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/sowmiya-nagarajan/" 
      class="fa fa-linkedin"> sowmiya-nagarajan</a>
      <a href="https://github.com/strangest-quark" class="fa fa-
      github"> strangest-quark</a>
      <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/strangely-quark" 
      class="fa fa-snapchat-ghost"> strangely-quark</a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/nagarajan.sowmiya" 
      class="fa fa-facebook">&nbsp;</a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/strange._.quark/" 
      class="fa fa-instagram"> </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @JohnConde. I edited my answer. Hope it's getting better